# Python get index range of all substring occurrences in string

Tags: python, string

What is the best way to get all of the the first and last index pairs of a substring in a string?

For example, if my string, s is "abcdegf", the substring "bcd" is s[1:4].

This function gets me the answer, but I would be surprised if there is not a more elegant solution.

```
>>> def substring_range(s, substring):
    for i in range(len(s)-len(substring)):
        if s[i:i+len(substring)] == substring:
            yield (i, i+len(substring))


>>> [x for x in substring_range('abcdabcd', 'bc')]
[(1, 3), (5, 7)]
```

Comment: `"abcdegf".index("bcd")` and `"abcdegf".index("bcd") + len("bcd")`?

Comment: `str.find` and `str.index` both return the index of the substring. To get the index range, you could just have a tuple with that index as the first value, and the index plus the substring's length as the second value.

Comment: @RandomDavis that is true, but I would only be able to find the first occurrence of the substring. I'll update to make sure finding all occurrences is a condition.

Comment: I've updated my answer with multiple occurences support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may leverage regular expressions, `match.start()` will returnt he start position and `match.end()` will provide the end position (the search is a literal string, so it must be `re.escape`d):

```
import re
def substring_range(s, substring):
    for i in re.finditer(re.escape(substring), s):
        yield (i.start(), i.end())

s = "abcdegfbcd"
substring = "bcd"
print([x for x in substring_range(s, substring)])
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/A40RVu)

Answer (score 2):

Something like that maybe?

```
control_s, sub_str = "abcdegfbcd", "bcd"

def subs_str_finder(control_s, sub_str):
    """
    Finds indexes of all sub_str occurences in control_s.
    """
    sub_len = len(sub_str)

    while sub_str in control_s:
        first_index = control_s.find(sub_str)
        second_index = first_index + sub_len
        yield first_index, second_index

        control_s = control_s.replace(sub_str, "", 1)

for first_index, second_index in subs_str_finder(control_s, sub_str):
    print(first_index, second_index)
```

**UPD**: Support for multiple substring occurences.