# How to find a whole word in a sentence in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have a sentence

```
sent = "Luxred is a great,awesome and amazing but, they make a lot of money too"
ents = ['L'Oreal', 'Maybelline', 'Garnier Natural', 'Luxred', 'Lux']
```

The sentences will be like this. The sentences will have commas and other words too. I want to find the exact word match for Luxred. It shouldn't match for Lux either and also want the starting index & ending index of the word. Here it is (0, 5). The sentence might change and the search words might come in between etc. How do I do this ?

Already tried using find.

```
def annotFinal (label, entities, sentences) :
finaldict = []
for sent in sentences :
    sent = str(sent).lower()
    inner_list = []
    for ent in entities :
        if (sent.find(ent) != -1) :
            inner_tup = (sent.find(ent), sent.find(ent) + len(ent), label)
            inner_list.append(inner_tup)
    inner_dict={'entities': sorted(inner_list, key=lambda x: x[0])}
    finaldict.append((sent, inner_dict))
return finaldict
```

Comment: You need to show minimal effort, and an error that you are receiving. Not simply expect us to do the work for you..

Comment: I already did using .find but unfortunately, I don't want substrings, I want the whole word and the indexes. Commas and other characters could also come in between, so splitting the sentences would also be a little hectic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python get index range of all substring occurrences in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100306/python-get-index-range-of-all-substring-occurrences-in-string)

Comment: Actually, if "bcdabcab, bc abc" is a sentence, the only "bc" that it should detect is the second word.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
re.search('r\bLuxred\b',sent)
```

If you need need everything in `ents` then you could do:

```
d = {i:re.search(f'\\b{i}\\b',sent) for i in ents}
d['Luxred']
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `find` method:

```
>>> sent = "Luxred is a great,awesome and amazing but, they make a lot of money too"
>>> sent.find("Luxred")
0
```

Comment: I did that but the problem is if there is another word called Luxreddo, it'll still return. Unfortunately, I only want if the whole word exists.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it done by using the following -

```
re.search(r"\b" + word + r"\b", sentence)
```

Gets the complete word & doesn't return out substrings like "cat" from "caterpillar" alone.